# How do you "forget" Apple TV on iDevice and Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, appletv

Is it possible to make devices “forget” Apple TV? I have reset my Apple TV, and now it’s listed as Apple TV(2) even though its name is set to “Apple TV”.

#### Screenshots:

[image: AirPlay screenshot]

[image: Menu dropdown screenshot]

Comment: Where exactly? Could you clarify a little more?

Comment: Basically everywhere. My Mac, iPhone and iPad, they all list this TV as Apple TV(2). I know I can rename the TV, but that's not the point. Screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/Iyip5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible. Airplay devices work like wifi networks: when it's needed, the iDevice scans to check what is available in range. There is no option regarding Airplay: it just appears when you are close enough to a capable device.

Answer (score 0):

Swipe up, select air play Apple TV, Turn Off Air Play Mirring, then select Apple TV. It sounds too simple, but it worked for me. Hope this helps.